# Removing duplicates from a list

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a list of strings and I need to remove the duplicates. I have tried a number of things, such as:

- Using [`listRemoveDuplicates(list,",",true);`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSd8001ae4abdbd911-7fc6f4b01350d8e2282-8000.html)
- Using [Ben Nadel's approach](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/432-Using-ColdFusion-Structures-To-Remove-Duplicate-List-Values.htm).
- Using the [ListDeleteDuplicates](http://www.cflib.org/udf/ListDeleteDuplicates) udf

Unfortunately, none of them worked.  I'm really not sure what is going on. So any help would be appreciated.

I am currently using a free Developer's version of ColdFusion 10 in case that affects things.

Sample List:

> lacunar_DM, Homocysteine, HTN, Tobacco, undetermined
>   ,lacunar_DM,Homocysteine,Tobacco

This was created by appending a static list with a dynamic one pulled from a database:

```
<cfsavecontent variable= "lacunar_list">
lacunar_DM,
Homocysteine,
HTN,
Tobacco,
undetermined
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset combination = ListAppend(lacunar_list, lacunar)>

<cfoutput>
List before removing dups: #combination#<br/>
List after removing dups: #listremoveduplicates(combination, ",", true)#<br/>
</cfoutput>
```

Here are the results:

List before removing dups:

> lacunar_DM, Homocysteine, HTN, Tobacco, undetermined
>   ,lacunar_DM,Homocysteine,Tobacco

List after removing dups:

> lacunar_DM, Homocysteine, HTN, Tobacco, undetermined
>   ,lacunar_DM,Homocysteine,Tobacco

Comment: Please provide some of your code.

Comment: And provide an example of the string with duplicates that you want removed.

Comment: Post a small *self-contained* repro case that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: What is `listRemoveDuplicates` - this isn't a built-in CF function... is it your own function?

Comment: listremoveDuplicates is a supported function as of coldfusion 10 ~This is from Adobe Website~   Description
Removes duplicate values (if they exist) in a list.

Returns
List sans duplicate values

Syntax
ListRemoveDuplicates(list[, delimiter] [, ignoreCase])

Properties
Parameter

Description

list

Required. List of objects.

delimiter

Optional. Character(s) that separate list elements. The default value is comma. .

ignoreCase

Optional. If true, ignores the case of strings in the list. By default the value is set to false.

Comment: My mistake - i didn't notice it on their page listing all the new functions, and it's not on [their list of all List functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a42). Here's the [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSd8001ae4abdbd911-7fc6f4b01350d8e2282-8000.html) for anyone interested in it!

Comment: Thanks for the link @duncan. (Added to the OP for better visibility)

Comment: The problem might be you're specifying a comma as a list separator, but your lacunar_list actually uses comma + linebreaks (some combination of Chr(13) and/or Chr(10) presumably)

Comment: Is there a need for the cfsavecontent? Couldn't you also just say cfset lacunar_list = "lacunar_DM,Homocysteine,HTN,Tobacco,undetermined"? That would also take care of your unintended spacing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the list which you created with `cfsavecontent` has newline characters in it because each item in that list is on it's own line within `cfsavecontent`. Since the other list you are joining it with does not have the same whitespace, you are not going to get the correct results.

Generally, it is best to remove unnecessary whitespace from lists in Coldfusion.

Try this instead of using `cfsavecontent`:

```
<cfset lacunar_list = "lacunar_DM,Homocysteine,HTN,Tobacco,undetermined" >
<cfset combination = ListAppend(lacunar_list, lacunar)>
```

Comment: I did this exactly and it worked. Thank you! I was beyond frustrated and just couldn't see those white spaces. Thanks for your keen eyes.

Answer (score 8):

I think your problem is that your list contains extra white space.
" Homocysteine" and "Homocysteine" are not the same values. Likewise, " Tobacco" and "Tobacco" are not the same values.

```
lacunar_DM, Homocysteine, HTN, Tobacco, undetermined ,lacunar_DM,Homocysteine,Tobacco
-----------^-------------^----^--------^------------^------------X------------X
```

Comment: That was it Thank you. I hate when you stare at something for hours and you just can't see the obvious problem. Thanks for your fresh pair of eyes. :)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned already, your list items contain extra white space. Looking at your list, all the items are using `_` as spaces, so the simplest solution is to remove the spaces first, then remove the duplicates.

```
listRemoveDuplicates( Replace( YourList, " ", "", "ALL" ) )
```

If you do have some valid spaces, then I would suggest using a `Trim()` around the fields when you compile the list manually.

```
YourList = ListAppend( YourList, Trim( ListItem ) )
```

Comment: That was it. It's so nice to have all these fresh eyes take a look when I have lost perspective. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Make sure each item in the list has whitespace trimmed off. `" Tobacco"` does not equal `"Tobacco"` and will not be viewed as a duplicate. In your SQL query, trim the values to ensure there are no leading or trailing spaces. In your static list, make sure there are no spaces in between the commas.

Comment: Lol, You got me by about 30 seconds.

Comment: Totally missed that. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't have CF10, this is my preferred way to remove duplicates from a list.

```
<cfset newlist = [] />
<cfloop list="#combination#" index="i">
    <cfif NOT arrayFind(newlist,trim(i))> // can also use arrayFindNoCase
     <cfset arrayAppend(newlist,trim(i))>
 </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
    #arraytolist(newlist)#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: .. or [arrayFindNoCase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS98CF660A-0C9E-4e85-BBA1-89862B60EB4D.html) if you want to ignore case differences.